# creating oracle types in java

Tags: java, oracle, types

I want invoke a oracle function which is take one  in parameter type of **oracle types** and one out parameter type of **oralce types**.

code :

```
Connection connection = (Connection) parameters.get(SwingBenchTask.JDBC_CONNECTION);
boolean success = true;
// getObjArray returns one object array with values
Object[] object2Values = getObjArray("input.txt");
oracle.sql.StructDescriptor structDesc = oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName, connection);
oracle.sql.STRUCT object1 = new oracle.sql.STRUCT(structDesc, connection, object2Values);
String query = "{call ? :=change_offer(?,?)}";
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(query);
long executeStart = System.nanoTime();
try
{
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    stmt.setObject(2, object1, OracleTypes.STRUCT);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.STRUCT, OutTypeName);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    success = false;
    System.err.println("Error :" + ex);
}
```

the constructor of class oralce.sql.STRUCT throws following exception

**java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**

Comment: if you provide some code it would be easier to help you. My guess is that your sql returns multiple row but you only use one struct.

Comment: thanks @Marthin. its throws exception while create the object1. at that time no queries executed.

Comment: Please, post the code of `change_offer(?,?)`. I suspect the error resides in that stored function, not in your JDBC logic

Comment: @LukasEder : exception occurred in following line **oracle.sql.STRUCT object1 = new oracle.sql.STRUCT(structDesc, connection, object2Values);** . After that only am invoking __change_offer(?,?)__ function.

Comment: @Srini2k6: I'm sorry, I missed that fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the error. I give the type name with schema name.

```
oracle.sql.StructDescriptor structDesc = oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(schema.typeName, connection);
oracle.sql.STRUCT object1 = new oracle.sql.STRUCT(structDesc, connection, object2Values);
```